# Executing function to alter database every 15 minutes

Tags: php, cron

I am currently working on a project that runs online tournaments. Normally admins of the site will generate brackets when it is time for the tournaments to start, but we have run into inconsistent start times, etc. and i am looking into proper ways to automate this process.

I have looked into running cronjobs every x min to check if a bracket needs to be generated but i am worried about issue when it comes to overlapping cronjobs, having to create/manage cronjobs through cpanel etc.

I was thinking about other solutions and thought it would be great if a user could load a page, the backend checks timestamps and determines if the bracket should be generated. An event is then fired/set to begin the auto-generation process elsewhere so it does not impact user load times. I just do not know the best route of going about this.

PS: I just need an idea of the direction i should be looking into so i can learn how to solve this issue i am not looking to copy and paste code. I just haven't been able to find anything. All of my search results provide cronjob examples.

**EDIT**
After thinking about things could using this work?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax('Full Url Path Here');
})
```

I don't need to pass user input, or return any data i simply need a way to fire an event, it would be easy to include this only when needed via a helper class. Also i won't necessarily have to worry about users attempting to access i can restrict the route to ajax only requests and since nothing is needed/used on input or returned as output what can happen?

Comment: A cron job can be made to not overlap by using advisory locking, i.e. [`flock()`](http://php.net/flock); or use `/usr/bin/flock` itself in your cron configuration.

Comment: And even without those locks, how would cron jobs overlap when there is a 15 minutes interval in them? Does that script take so long to run?

Comment: We run a variety of tournaments some of them reaching 512 teams. Generating brackets won't take 15 min i was just thinking if there could be a possibility, i haven't dived into cronjobs extensively.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it everytime a user loads a page (idea not tested, but theoretically possible):

1) Create a file and store the timestamp of the last time you updated the database.

2) Everytime a user loads a page, read that timestamp and check if 15 minutes passed.

3) If 15 minutes passed: Run a background script (with [shell_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php)?) that will do what you want and update the timestamp when it's done executing.

One obvious flaw with this system is that if you have no visitors in let's say a 30 minute frame, you will miss 2 updates. Though I guess that if you have no visitors you also have no point in generating brackets?

Comment: I think checking every 15 min would be a waste on page load and when tournament registration is open i check if the registration should be closed so the db can update the registration status of the tournament. I was hoping to find a solution to incorporate there so i can just fire an event there that would do something like `finish pageload for user and fire this script in backend`. I am looking into shell exec now.

Comment: A simple file_get_contents on an almost empty file will have no effect on the page load time, but even if you think it will you can just put it after all of the HTML is rendered (below the footer part of your webpage). But you could also do this check in the actual script that you'll run with shell_exec if you want.